# Access current invoice and add line item in Quickbooks

Tags: c#, quickbooks

What XML would I use to access the currently open invoice in quickbooks and add, and then modify, a line item? I am using SDKTestPlus3 for the moment.

FYI, I couldn't open the sample template because it couldn't find the qbfc interop, so I'm not using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QuickBooks SDK doesn't offer any way to get the currently open transaction. Sorry!

You can, however, open a specified invoice for the user. See this request type in the [QuickBooks OSR](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html):

- TxnDisplayMod

You can also use InvoiceMod to update an existing invoice. Look up this in the OSR:

- InvoiceMod